# Passing keycloak configuration parameters in the code rather than reading from application.properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, single-sign-on, redhat, keycloak

In my SpringBoot application, I pass my keycloak configuration parameters in the application.properties file. However, I'd like to know if there is a way to let keycloak read these parameters from the code rather than from application.properties.

For example, I retrieve the Realm, Server URL, ClientID and other parameters from a database, I'd like to tell keycloak to read from the database directly or from String that I declare when it launches.

Is that possible?

Thank you

Comment: Actually how will you pass the custom params from application.properties to keycloak?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to [KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/adapters/oidc/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/keycloak/adapters/springboot/KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver.java), your database reader class must implement `KeycloakConfigResolver` and should be provided as bean.

```
public class KeycloakDBConfigResolver implements org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakConfigResolver {

 @Override
 public KeycloakDeployment resolve(OIDCHttpFacade.Request request) {
    //Read keycloak configuration from Database
   }
}
```

`resolve()` method should read keycloak configuration from Database and construct KeycloakDeployment.